# kernel_task cpu usage 300% plus long press power button to start Mac Air

Tags: mac, kernel, osx-yosemite, cpu-usage

I'm having Mac Air 13inch 2014  having 4 gb memory and 120 gb Hard disk , from the few days i have been facing a problem that kernel_task is taking 300% of my cpu and my mac is running very slow and also it doesn't starts up until i press the power button for 30 seconds .

Things i have tried :

- Fresh Installation of OS X Yosemite
- Reset The SMC
- Reset The PRAM

All in vain the kernel_task is still appearing and i also run the apple hardware test but it shows no Errors in Hardware .

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

This is Yosemite's way of cooling your machine.

> Activity Monitor may show that a process named kernel_task is using a large percentage of your CPU, and during this time you may notice a lot of fan activity. This process helps manage temperature by making the CPU less available to processes that are using the CPU intensely. In other words, kernel_task responds to conditions that cause your CPU to become too hot. When the temperature decreases, kernel_task automatically reduces its activity.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203184

The underlying issue may be another process, or even that the airflow is blocked, causing overheat.

Comment: Yeesh... nothing like an elegant solution, like DVFS for example...

Comment: What you wrote is helpful in the sense it explains the direct cause of the issue. The question, however, is how to identify and solve the root cause.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209575/why-is-kernel-task-using-so-much-cpu