# Process 0 is taking 500%+ CPU time in MAC

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, mac, operating-systems

### Problem

When I boot my mac, once the login screen appears and after which everything freezes, I can hardly open any applications.

### Analysis

Using activity manager, I found out, process with process id 0 is taking 500%+ time, due to which other processes are not able to get executed. As this process is the first process and it's kernel's process which is only responsible for paging, Ideally it shouldn't consume cpu time at this scale.

What are the possible reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kernel\_task cpu usage 300% plus long press power button to start Mac Air](https://superuser.com/questions/961623/kernel-task-cpu-usage-300-plus-long-press-power-button-to-start-mac-air)

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209575/why-is-kernel-task-using-so-much-cpu